Can I use SATA traces on PCB for USB 3.0?
Can I use SATA traces (SSD_RX+/- & SSD_TX+/-) on a PCB for USB 3.0 data transfer? I am designing a test system for PCBs. There are SATA lines and I think this 2 pairs can use for USB 3.0 data lines (SSRX+/- & SSTX+/-). I designed an adaptor card PCB, use USB 3.0 connectors and 3.0 impedance. Because 3.0's diff impedance almost same with SATA. But I can't see any device on system completed when put a USB flash driver end of the lines.


So what does the system wires and what it doesn't? Power? USB2?

Actually everything is OK on pin to pin test. The cable is quality 3.0. I do not use 2.0 lines because I do not need them. I checked what my design PCB and it is OK too. But when my adapter PCB and tested PCB mated, PC is not detect USB device. Test diagram is like this: PC-->usb 3.0 cable-->adapter PCB-->tested PCB -->2nd adapter PCB--> usb3.0 flash disk. Test is measure of flash disk's read/write speed.

I still can't figure out how the flash disk receives power from where. It surely does not go through SATA wiring which is for data only. Please draw a diagram, show schematics and PCB layout of your adapters, etc. Generally USB3 does not require USB2 pair to work. But you must have USB3 port on PC and memory stick.

I explained a little bit less, sorry. Power is connected externally cable. GND is already common in both of PCB's.D+ and D- is not connected. I just using what 2 pair rx/tx +/- connections on tested PCB.

In addition; I tried usb 2.0 connection with each rx and tx pairs. It is perfectly working without much loss. So, normally usb 2.0 and 3.0 both of them 90 ohm %10+/- tolerance. Why 2.0 works and 3.0 does not ?

SATA and USB 3.0 are completely different protocols - are you trying to plug a USB device into a SATA controller and expecting it to work as USB? If not, please draw a diagram/provide photos/schematic of what you are trying to do

What are 'SATA traces'?  Is this some existing design you're reusing the PCB from?  A differential pair is a differential pair, they use a similar bit rate (frequency), and if the impedance matches then the signal doesn't care.  But it's strange to talk about it this way, especially if you say you use USB connectors - presumably the existing PCB is designed for SATA connectors? Although there's a long tradition of abusing connectors for the 'wrong' protocol - I've seen PCIe over USB, HDMI, and other connectors.  Another possibility is you have RX and TX mixed up somehow.

I added the basically diagram of system. All grounds are commmon. And gnd (2.0)-gnd_drain(3.0) are common too. There are no components on these paths in both the adapter PCB and the tested PCB. There are only paths from connector to connector. There isn't even any capacitors.

@esat Looks like your diagrams are either inaccurate or you are missing connections such as Vbus so USB stick does not receive power.

Lines like 5v and gnd are fine, I just showed them as a single cable in the diagram. Apart from that, in addition to 5v and gnd, other pins also beep without any problems when the pin to pin test is performed. I'm sure the connections are correct, am I having problems when going to high speeds?

@esat We can't understand what you simplified out and what you have done  correctly and incorrectly. Is the SATA ground connected? What's on the PCB that routes SATA, just direct traces between connectors? How long are any cables you have used?

@Justme SATA GND is common and connected to all GNDs. The schematic diagram shows the basic state of the system. Think of a USB 3.0 cable, male to male. A USB 3.0 flash memory is inserted at the end. We separate the 4 superspeed differential lines in the cable and take them over the PCBs. All remaining connections are connected externally. We want to benchmark the flash disk with the PC, we want to test superspeed connections on tested PCB. SATA lines on PCB are only traces.there are just 4 pcs rx/tx +/- traces on tested PCB.

@esat OK, USB male to male cable sounds suspicious. Do you mean Type-A, Type-C or which kind of cable, what connectors it has on each end? Does the PC have USB3? Which connector, A or C? Which connector the flash disk has, A or C? There is just so many important details you are not telling, and you likely are unaware why they are important details that are required to solve your problem.

you right, this is my first experience with high high speed signals. sorry for the less info.
I use high speed vita 46 connectors from TE, and USB for 3.0 connector from WE. all USB types are type A. Total length of traces at three PCB is almost 400mm. cable is 1.5m quality cable. Like I said, when i checked pin to pin connection, everything seems OK. I will research your advice.

It sounds like the problem might be related to your physical layout, part selection, etc.  It is very hard to tell anything without photos of your actual setup.
